# How to prove that $\pi \in \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I just read how you can show that $\sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{R}$ by using the Nested Intervals Theorem. It starts by making two sequences of finite decimal numbers that converge to $\sqrt{2}$. Namely, $x_k$ being the largest k-digit decimal greater than 1 such that $x_k^2<2$ while $y_k$ being the smallest k-digit decimal such that $y_k^2>2$.

This was possible from knowing the behavior of the digits of $\sqrt{2}$.

But I was curious how can I prove that $\pi \in \mathbb{R}$ when we don't know nothing about how the digit behave for $\pi$?

Comment: If $\,\pi\,$ exists, it can only be real. How to prove that it exists depends on the particular definition of $\,\pi\,$ that you are using.

Comment: Any answer to this question is going to have to make some assumption about how to define $\pi$; you might get more useful answers if you state the definition(s) that you're familiar with.

Comment: Is it enough to say that since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, and I can find a sequence of $\mathbb{Q}$ that converges to $\pi$ (using $n<\pi<n+1$ and Nested Intervals Theorem), hence $\pi \in \mathbb{R}?$

Comment: Every limit of sequence of rational numbers is in real number, is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that would be enough. But that seems to miss the point: how are you proposing to find the desired rational sequence?

Comment: @EricStucky By keep dividing the interval in half where $n < \pi < n+1$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Beginning with $a_1 = n$ and $b_1 = n+1$ and we divide the interval $[a_1,b_1]$ in half where one of the half-intervals will contain $\pi$. If we keep doing this then we get a sequence of rational numbers that converge to $\pi$. This was actually a proof to prove that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. I was just confused by my book providing the proof for $\sqrt{2}\in\mathbb{R}$ while I thought $\mathbb{Q}$ being dense in $\mathbb{R}$ was enough.

Comment: @user3000482 `keep dividing the interval in half where n<π<n+1` This only works if $\pi$ is a real, but that's what you want to prove, so any such approach is circular. As told before and repeated in previous comments, you need to first spell out what your definition is for $\,\pi\,$, before attempting to prove that it's real (or recognizing that such attempt doesn't make sense).

Comment: @dxiv Thank you I finally understand.... I was confused why was there need to prove $\sqrt{2}\in\mathbb{R}$ when I thought it seemed obvious from $\mathbb{Q}$ being dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @dxiv Can I use the definition of $\pi$ as the circumference divided by the diameter? Is this impossible to relate to what we do here?

Comment: It strikes me as this being easy:  $\pi$ is the result of dividing two real numbers, and the denomenator is not 0.  The quotient of any two real numbers is a real number (unless the denominator is 0).

Comment: @user3000482 The ratio between the circumference and diameter of any given circle *is* of course a real number. If you prove that said ratio is the *same* for *all* circles then, yes, you have proved that a unique real number exists - commonly known as $\,\pi\,$ - which can be defined as the circumference-to-diameter ratio for an arbitrary circle. How you prove the geometric part, however, depends in turn on the axioms you are using for your geometry, and will likely involve calculus for defining the lengths of non-rectilinear paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is bit strange. The way $\pi$ is defined it turns out to be a real number (similar to the fact that the way $i$ is defined it turns out not to be a real number).

Let's first clarify the situation for $\sqrt{2}$. The symbol $\sqrt{2}$ is supposed to be defined as a number $x$ of some kind such that $x^{2}=2$. The idea is that numbers of these kind exist and can be manipulated using the usual arithmetic operations of $+, -, \times, /$. It is a basic fact of number theory that there is no rational number whose square is $2$ (and I hope you are aware of its proof). So such a number like $\sqrt{2}$ can't lie in the rational number system. Fortunately there is a beautiful system $\mathbb {R} $ of real numbers with the following property:

> **Theorem**: If $a$ is a positive real number and $n$ is a positive integer then there is a unique positive real number $b$ such that $b^{n} =a$. This unique number $b$ is denoted by symbol $\sqrt[n] {a} $ and called the $n$'th root of $a$.

The proof of this theorem can be given in many ways including the use of nested interval principle. And putting $n=a=2$ we see that there is a unique positive real number $\sqrt{2}$ such that $(\sqrt{2})^{2}=2$. It is via the use of the above theorem that the concept of $n$'th root is defined.

There is a similar theorem on the basis of which one defines the length of certain curves (including circles) and then $\pi$ is a real number which is length of a circle of diameter $1$. It is in this way that we may define real number $\pi$. The proof of the theorem regarding length of curves can also be done via properties of real numbers, but we don't usually apply nested interval principle here. You should study this topic of length of curves in some detail. One possible option to do so is my [blog post](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2012/07/functions-of-bounded-variation-part-2.html).

Another approach is to use the theorem that regions bounded by certain curves have a well defined area and then define $\pi$ as the area of a circle with radius $1$. This is simpler and more popular and perhaps you know it if you have studied calculus.

Answer (score 4):

An answer similar in spirit to your example could be based on Leibniz' series for $\frac{\pi}{4}$ which requires a bit of calculus, in particular knowledge of the Taylor series for the $\tan^{-1}$ function.  Leibniz' series is $$\frac{\pi}{4}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}$$
As the series alternates the partial sums will be above and below the sum $\frac{\pi}{4}$, so we are indeed approaching $\frac{\pi}{4}$ with rational sequences from above and from below (but quite slowly).
$$
\begin{array}
ss_0 &= 1 \\
s_1 & = 1-\frac{1}{3} = \frac{2}{3} \\
s_2 & = 1-\frac{1}{3} +\frac{1}{5} = \frac{13}{15} \\
\dots
\end{array}$$

Comment: If you consider that to be the *definition* of $\,\pi\,$, then no proof is necessary that it's real, since the limit of *any* real convergent series is real. Otherwise, you need to *prove* that Leibniz' series does indeed converge to $\pi /4$ according to whatever other definition of $\pi$ the OP is using.

Comment: @dxiv Yes, I would define $2\pi$ as the limit of the circumference of the regular $n$-gons. It is a real number by definition

Comment: @user1952009 That can be made to work, but note that it's not as trivial as you make it sound, either. You need to prove that the ratio does not depend on the size of the $n$-gon, then justify passing to the limit. Once you did all that, yes, you have a definition for $\,\pi\,$, and you can look at proving Leibniz' series.

Comment: @dxiv The convergence depends on the axioms of geometry or on $\lim_{ x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$

Comment: @user1952009 All I was saying is that tt depends on what axioms you are using, and $\sin(x) / x \to 1$ is usually not one of them. The intuition is good, and the construction *can* be formalized to work, but one still needs be careful with pointing out all the implicit assumptions along the way.

Answer (score 0):

We may obtain sequences of approximations to $\pi$ from below and from above using the series

$$\pi = \frac{25}{8}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{360}{(4k+2)(4k+4)(4k+5)(4k+7)(4k+8)(4k+10)}$$

and

$$\pi = \frac{22}{7}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{240}{(4k+5)(4k+6)(4k+7)(4k+9)(4k+10)(4k+11)}$$

to obtain the inequality

$$\frac{25}{8}<\frac{1759}{560}<\frac{87803}{27720}<...\pi...<\frac{141514}{45045}<\frac{10886}{3465}<\frac{22}{7}$$

Comment: From my previous comment: "*This only works if $\pi$ is a real, but that's what you want to prove, so any such approach is circular*". Saying that $\,\pi\,$ equals the limit of a convergent real series pre-supposes that $\,\pi\,$ is a real. Saying that a real number is less than (or greater than) $\,\pi\,$ pre-supposes that $\,\pi\,$ is a real. The OP asked to *prove* that $\,\pi\,$ is a real, while your answer *assumes* that.

Comment: @dxiv If we use the rhs of the series only, prove that they converge to the same number and then label this number as $\pi$, would that avoid the problem?

Comment: Then you would have just defined $\,\pi\,$ as the limit of a convergent real series, so it would of course be a real number with nothing left to prove. The OP *still* hasn't clarified what their definition of $\,\pi\,$ might be, which would require a *proof* that it's a real number.